# Application Performance monitoring on Swisscom Application Cloud

Tags: swisscomdev

I am investigating options for monitoring our installation in Swisscom's cloud-foundry. My objectives are the following:

- monitor performance indicators for deployed application (such as cpu, disk, memory)
- monitor performance indicators for services (slow queries, number of queries, ideally also some metrics on hitting quotas)

So far, I understand the options are the following (including some BUTs):

1. I used a very nice TOP cf-plugin ([github](https://github.com/ECSTeam/cloudfoundry-top-plugin))
   This works very well. It seems that it registers itself to get the required firehose nozzles and consume data.

That is very useful for tracing / ad-hoc monitoring, but not very good for a serious infrastructure monitoring.

2. Another way I found is to use [firehose-syslog](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog) solution.

This can be deployed as an app to (as far as I understand) do the job in similar way, as the TOP cf plugin.

The problem is, that it requires registered client, so it can authenticate with the doppler endpoint. For some reason, the top-cf-plugin does that automatically / in another way.

3. Last option i am considering is to build the monitoring itself to the App (using a special buildpack)

That can be for example done with [Datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/cloud_foundry/). But it seems to also require a dedicated uaa client to register the Nozzle.

I would like to check, if somebody is (was) on the similar road, has some findings.

**Eventually I would like to raise the following questions towards the swisscom community support:**

- is it possible to register uaac client to be able to ingest events through the firehose nozzle from external service? (this requires admin credentials if I was reading correctly)
- is there an alternative way to authenticate with the nozzle (for example using a special user and his authentication token?)
- is there any alternative to monitor the CF deployments in Swisscom? Eventually, is there a paper, blogpost or other form of documentation, that would be helpful in this respect (also for other users of AppCloud)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it requires admin permissions, we can not give out UAA clients for the firehose.
However, there are different ways to get metrics in context of a user.

1. **CF API**

   You can obtain basic metrics of a specific app by polling the CF API:
   https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/5.0.0/apps/get_detailed_stats_for_a_started_app.html

   However, since you have to poll (and for each app), it's not the recommended way.
2. **Metrics in syslog drain**

   CF allows devs to forward their logs to syslog drains; in more recent versions, CF also sends metrics to this syslog drain (see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#container-metrics). 
   For example, you could use Swisscom's Elasticsearch service to store these metrics and then analyze it using Kibana.
3. **Metrics using loggregator (firehose)**

   The firehose allows streaming logs to clients for two types of roles:
   Streaming *all* logs to admins (which requires a UAA client with admin permissions) and streaming *app* logs and metrics to devs with permissions in the app's space. This is also what the `cf logs` command uses. `cf top` also works this way [(it enumerates all apps and streams the logs of each app).](https://github.com/ECSTeam/cloudfoundry-top-plugin/blob/v0.9.3/top/client.go#L177-L201)
   However, you will find out that most open source tools that leverage the firehose only work in admin mode, since they're written for the platform operator.

Of course you also have the possibility to monitor your app by instrumenting it (white box approach), for example by configuring Spring actuator in a Spring boot app or by including an agent of your favourite APM vendor (Dynatrace, AppDynamics, ...)

I guess this is the most common approach; we've seen a lot of teams having success by instrumenting their applications. Especially since advanced monitoring anyway requires you to create your own metrics as the firehose provided cpu/memory metrics are not that powerful in a microservice world.

However, option 2. would be worth a try as well, especially since the ELK's stack metric support is getting better and better.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply, the -type merics is actually golden! (i've updated my drains plugin). The option 3 is interesting as well, I just have problems passing my credentials (client-id, client-secret - possibly bearer token) through the firehose-syslog.

Comment: @LukasFutera client id und secret is only used when authenticating as admin client to firehose. when acting in context of a user, you actually authenticate with a bearer token that you got from UAA as a user before (with username and password or single sign on). that you can only pass client id and secret to firehose-syslog is probably because the project only supports the admin interaction.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I will try to find some alternative software. Do you know if it is in plan to introduce performance logging also for the services provided for Swisscom - for example MariaDB / Mongo ? Thanks, Lukas

Comment: @LukasFutera We always have customers asking for it; however, it's quite an hard/advanced task and it's quite low in the backlog. you can help prioritize it higher if you speak to your customer rep :)